# How to destroy a dynamically created part in eclipse 4 rcp

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Can anybody please help me out on how to destroy a dynamically created part. I am using partservice to create a part dynamically from a partdescriptor. i know we can hide the created part, But i think the context still has the object saved in some list so it is not removed from the heap space which in turn increases the memory. so is there a way where i can destroy the part like how we dispose a widget in SWT.

Answer (score 6):

Add `removeOnHide` to the `Tags` section of the part descriptor (and make sure it is copied to the created part!). This constant is declared in `EPartService`.